# Nexus 7 dual-boot with android?

Tags: dual-boot, android, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in parallel to Android on the Nexus 7 (dual-boot), or not?

If not, how hard would it be to add the feature? It should be just a matter of adding another partition and installing a boot manager, right?

Comment: Not sure.  But you would likely need a different ROM to be loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. See this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM4mn0_8qAI)  and follow the xda-developers thread linked there. In development.

Comment: You can find the forum post here <Use at your own risk>.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it with the current image but it has been requested.  At UDS it was discussed in several sessions and requested by people but there are no current plans to implement it.  [Here's the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1078391) that was opened where you can track any work that occurs.

Comment: It is possible.  And I have done it.  This answer may have been correct at the time, but it is no longer correct.