# Can I still use android?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is it possible to choose which system i'd like to run when I start the device. Probably not I think...

And if it's not working, is there anybody that works on a project that allows users to choose whether to boot android or ubuntu?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210870/nexus-7-dual-boot-with-android

Comment: Try to give more info on your question

Answer (score 0):

[MultiROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403) claims to support this use scenario.