# Dual-boot Android & Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nexus 7 dual-boot with android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210870/nexus-7-dual-boot-with-android)

Is it possible to run a Dual-boot of Ubuntu and Android on the same device or will it have to be one or the other? Im looking at possiby dual booting the N7 or HTC One X

Comment: The Ubuntu image for the Nexus 7 replaces your current ROM, other methods such as chrooting into Ubuntu don't requite you to dual-boot.

Comment: With it replacing the ROM can you return to Android or are you stuck using Ubuntu?

Comment: You have to make a back up of your Android ROM, so you can later put it back.

Comment: 1+ **Dual-Boot**, I would have never imagined that this sentence could be used for a cell-phone. Technology! Although actually it is not possible, for the time being..

Comment: @Lucio you can perfectly dual boot Android ROMs, you only need a kernel for your device that supports it.

Comment: @UriHerrera Wow, really? Well, I'm running right now to buy one of that tiny computers :P

Comment: Yes, I get it. I was joking just a little bit. And I don't know very much about ROMs and those things right now. Also you are right, it is a duplicated question.